# Detect head in an image

Tags: image-processing

I have an image of a person. The image contains only one person with a perfectly white background(image may contain front or back side of the body). I want to detect the head part of the image. How can I do that? Can anyone propose Algorithms?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

As you have an homogeneous background, I propose to use a skin detection. It uses simple thresholds into HSL / HSV color spaces.
If the image is gray level, you can use the Viola/Jones face detection algorithm.